# How to get the address of next block in memory management?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I read the code of memory management, and I can't understand the meaning of the following function, could you please tell how does the function work?

```
// Get the reference of next block's address in current block.
static void*& GetNextBlock(void* p_block)
{
      return *(reinterpret_cast<void**>(p_block));
}
```

According to the comment upon the code, the function returns the address of p_block's next block, but I think the function returns the address of p_block.

Comment: Try breaking this down into smaller chunks. Do you know what `reinterpret_cast<void **>()` does? If not, you can easily find the answer in your C++ textbook. Now that you know what it does, take a piece of paper and write down the explanation. Now, do you know what the unary `*` operator does? Ok, same approach. now, put two and two together, and you have your answer!

Comment: It looks like `p_block` contains an address of its next block.

Answer (score 4):

The `p_block` variable is an *address* of some piece of memory. You cast that to a `void**` with `reinterpret_cast<void**>(p_block)`, meaning it's now considered the address (A) of an address (B) in memory. Then you dereference that (with `*something`) to get the address `B`.

This scheme is often used in memory arenas where a memory block (usually a control segment *before* the memory addresses returned from `malloc`) contains the address of the next block (whether allocated or not). For example:

```
             +----------+    +----------+
firstFree -> | nextFree | -> | nextFree | -> nullptr
             +----------+    +----------+
             | user bit |    | user bit |
             +----------+    +----------+
```